# OnClick generate different Events when you click multiple times

Tags: java, android, events, onclick

I'm trying to get my OnClick to generate differente events when I click once or twice.
On the first click the ImageView changes, on the second it pass to a different Activity.

Here's my code for now

```
public static int i=0;

final ImageView srt = findViewById(R.id.imageone);
Button apply = findViewById(R.id.apply);
       apply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(50, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
              if(i==0){
                  srt.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagetwo);
             }else{
                  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Right now if I click once the ImageView change, but the second click does not work and doesn't change the Activity.

Comment: 1st does the onclick overridden method call when you click 2nd time2nd thing i didnt saw in the code that i value change to something else.everytime the value of i is 0 so that is the other way its not working.

Comment: @RituSumanMohanty Hi! Yeah I tried to add an else if with another value, like that :    if(i==0){
                  srt.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagetwo;
             }else if (i==1){
                 openthis();
                }                                                                                                                But it still doesn't work

Comment: where you change the value of i to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Ritu Suman Mohanty in the comments is correct.  You need to increment your value with `i++`;  Right now, `i == 0` is always true.  Good luck!